# Generalize awk function

Tags: bash, shell

In order to gain productivity, I use the following function to know which functions I have to alias because I use them the most:

```
function mu() {
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        history | awk '{CMD[$2]++;count++;}END { for (a in CMD)print CMD[a] " " CMD[a]/count*100 "% " a;}' | grep -v "./" | column -c3 -s " " -t | sort -nr | nl |  head -n10
    elif [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
        history | awk '$2=="'$1'"{CMD[$3]++;count++;}END { for (a in CMD)print CMD[a] " " CMD[a]/count*100 "% " a;}' | grep -v "./" | column -c3 -s " " -t | sort -nr | nl |  head -n10
    elif [[ $# -eq 2 ]]; then
        history | awk '$2=="'$1'"&&$3=="'$2'"{CMD[$4]++;count++;}END { for (a in CMD)print CMD[a] " " CMD[a]/count*100 "% " a;}' | grep -v "./" | column -c3 -s " " -t | sort -nr | nl |  head -n10
    fi
}
```

This function works with 0, 1 or 2 arguments, showing the most used argument just after the arguments the function gets as input.

Is there a way to make this works for any number of arguments?

The command should look like this for 4 and 5 arguments respectively :

```
history | awk '$2=="'$1'"&&$3=="'$2'"&&$4=="'$3'"{CMD[$5]++;count++;}END { for (a in CMD)print CMD[a] " " CMD[a]/count*100 "% " a;}' | grep -v "./" | column -c3 -s " " -t | sort -nr | nl |  head -n10
history | awk '$2=="'$1'"&&$3=="'$2'"&&$4=="'$3'"&&$5=="'$4'"{CMD[$6]++;count++;}END { for (a in CMD)print CMD[a] " " CMD[a]/count*100 "% " a;}' | grep -v "./" | column -c3 -s " " -t | sort -nr | nl |  head -n10
```

Basically, each argument should add another condition like `&&$4=="'$3'"` and change the number inside the brackets just after `[$6]`.

And here is the expected output:

```
mu
     1  1065  13,3861%    cd
     2  1007  12,6571%    ls
     3  761   9,56511%    vim
     4  755   9,48969%    docker-compose
     ...

mu ls                      
     1  823  81,7279%
     2  12   1,19166%    logs
     3  5    0,496524%   mnt
     ...
```

and so on.

Comment: If you could add sample input and sample outputs in your post we could provide you better solutions, please do so and let us know on same.

Comment: and how would look your command for 7 arguments?

Comment: I've added details to the question, thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that :

```
function mu() {
    history | awk -v input="$@" -v pos="$((2 + $#))" '( substr($0, index($0,$2)) ~ "^" input){CMD[$pos]++;count++} END{ for (a in CMD) print CMD[a] " " CMD[a]/count*100 "% " a}' | grep -v "./" | column -c3 -s " " -t | sort -nr | nl | head -n10
}
```

Here, the heavy work is done by `-v input="$@" -v pos="$((2 + $#))"` and `( substr($0, index($0,$2)) ~ "^" input)` : we convert our array of argument into the string `input`. Then we compare it with the beginning of our history command. If it matches, we use the `pos` variable to determine which field to display.

**Side note:** for `zsh`, simply replace `pos="$((4 + $#))"` and `index($0,$4)` to get the same results.

Comment: Thank you, it works really well, except that I occasionally get the following error: `awk: fatal: cannot open file '-f' for reading (No such file or directory)`. It looks like the error appears when I have multiple arguments and only a few results, do you have any idea why? (I'm using zsh with your side note)

Comment: @Cydonia7 I'm sorry, I'm unable to reproduce this bug on my machine :/

Answer (score 1):

if you do not mind using perl,

perl switches:

- `-n` like sed loop over input without printing
- `-a` autosplit, line into `@F` array

```
mu() {
  history | 
  perl -ane '
    BEGIN {
      @a = @ARGV;   # read parameters to @a
      @ARGV = ();   # clear parameters to avoid reading form file
    }
    $F[$_+1] eq $a[$_] or next LINE for 0..$#a; # loop over parameters check are equal to line fields otherwise continue with next line
    ++$H{$F[@a+1]};      # increment hash value whose key is field after last parameter
    ++$tot;              # increment total
    END {
      @r = sort { $H{$b} <=> $H{$a} }  # numeric sort over values
        keys %H;
      if (@r>10) {
         @r = @r[0..9]
      }
      printf "%s\t%.2f%%\t%s\n", $H{$_}, 100*$H{$_}/$tot, $_ for @r
    }
  ' "$@"    # pass parameter arguments
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like to keep it in Bash if possible but I will still take a look at your program.